# Can a local Drush 8 be used to send commands to a remote site which uses Drush 9?

Tags: drush

Let's say we have a dev-ops administrator who isn't a developer and doesn't want/need a local copy of the website. As of Drupal 8.4, Drush 9 is required, and Drush 9 doesn't have a way to install it globally, but Drush 8 still does.

Can Drush 8 be used locally with aliases for a remote Drupal 8.4 site which has Drush 9 as a dependency?
Is there another way to use  Drush 9 locally without building the entire site?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 doesn't require Drush 9. Users who are updating Drupal to Drupal 8.4 need to first update Drush to Drush 8.1.12 or higher.  (See [Drupal 8.4.0 release notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.4.0)).

I use Drush 8.1.15 with Acquia aliases to do a lot of things, for example clearing the cache, updating the database, synchronizing the local database with the production server.

You may need to figure out the connection requirements (like SSH keys and the like), but there is no reason a dev-op can't use Drush 8.

Comment: Drupal 8.4+ does require Drush 9, though it still works with Drush 8 (unofficially).
http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: Interesting conflict between docs.  Drupal release notes (link above) clearly say 8.1.12.  I've been using 8.1.14 with 8.4 for since it was released and have yet to find a problem.  So I think Drupal.org wins out. :)  Seems like drush.org is trying to simplify a bit.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is along the lines of tenken, but I'll add some more details.

To answer your actual question first: Yes, you can probably use a local Drush 8 to control a remote site using Drush 9 for quite some time, until they differ too much. I wouldn't recommend it.

Having Drush 9 on a local computer doesn't require to have a local Drupal site. Installing it "globally" for the current user is as easy as running `composer global require drush/drush`.

Then you can the */vendor/bin* directory that contains Drush to PATH for convenience. This should be perfectly suitable for dev-ops administrators.

PS: Installing Drush 9 as part of a Drupal site saves some package downloads, 24 versus 35 when I tested it, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume install drush 9 locally to a project, but still use alias files for all your remote systems. eg, treat the local installation as a globally installed service conceptually.

if you dont like a random project on your system hosting drush this way stick it on a VM or Container and interact with drush there.